# Facebook Hashtags (Highlighting inside the textarea)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hashtag

I want to `highlight the text` inside the `textarea` as facebook does. A solution to this is to keep an external div and highlight, as in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HR5N8/). But then there might be multiple highlighted field and then there position and width will have to be calculated at every instant, which seems very complex. Also backspace should remove the complete tag at once. Any way in which these `hashtags` can be implemented or any sample code implementing the same technique above?

[image: As Html is highlighted here]

Comment: Here is an angularjs directive which creates a content editable div with support for facebook like hashtags highlights
https://github.com/sujeet100/ngHashtags Similar logic can be used to create what you want without using angularjs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The highlighting is occurring on a background layer that is updated on a keyup event listener (the `textarea` is transparent (`background-color: rgba(0,​ 0,​ 0,​ 0)`)).  This is what it looks like if you add some `padding-top` to the textarea (the highlight doesn't have an opportunity to update):

[image]

Facebook's approach is actually really clever, as you type in the text area the contents are evaluated and sent to a background element that looks like this:

```
<span class="highlighterContent"><b>#html</b> This is </span>
```

The `<b>` element has the following css:

```
.uiMentionsInput .highlighter b {
    background: linear-gradient(#DCE6F8, #BDCFF1) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #A3BCEA;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

The smart thing is the span behind the text area has a transparent font so it takes the same space as the opaque font of the text area (allowing the `<b>` highlight to stay aligned with the textarea text).  Smart guys over there :)

Comment: Haha, really? Never knew. I thought it was contentEditable-magic. I must investigate this further. +1 btw.

Comment: I wonder if that's still the only way to do it in 2023. I've just implemented my input with similar approach, but I've noticed that instagram's input is converting tags to spans on the fly, without any caret position issues using contentEditable attribute.

Answer (score 0):

you can make something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/HR5N8/

```
<div id="something" contentEditable="true">
    Hi, my name is <span class="name">John</span> and i'm 20 years old!    
</div>

#something{
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

.name{
     background: #E1EEF5;   
}
```

Comment: I tried this way, but the issue with using div is that I can't add a placeholder to it. Any way the placeholder can be added?

Comment: Worst way... How do you identify the position of each tags. It should be something relative to the width of the content.